# Yarn web UI is not running

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm working with Hadoop 2.9 with a very minimal configuration. In particular, I didn't set any ports, everything is running with default ports.

When I start Hadoop with the command *start-all.sh*, the Yarn ResourceManager and NodeManager are running, according to the result of command *ps -ef | grep yarn*.

Yet the Yarn web UI doesn't seem to be running as netstat -l returns no port 8088 listening. I haven't figured out how it is supposed to start. Is there a configuration parameter that will fire it ?

Comment: Yes, there is a configuration parameter, but the defaults are mostly fine, and you should go look at the log files for errors before you check network ports

Comment: I looked at the logs and thre are no exceptions occuring.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the issue. In the yarn-site.xml file, I had:

```
   <property>
     <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
     <value>localhost</value>
     <description>The hostname of the ResourceManager</description>
   </property>
```

Despite localhost being correctly defined in /etc/hosts, Hadoop seems to accept only IP addresses or server names. Anyhow, removing this block entirely solved the problem.